# How to choose specific row and column indices in C++ Eigen Array?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I wonder how it is possible to choose specific elements in Eigen Array given lists of indices for rows and columns. For example:

```
array = [[1, 2, 3],
         [4, 5, 6],
         [7, 8, 9]]
rowIndices = [0, 1, 2]
colIndices = [0, 1, 2]

expectedResult = [1, 5, 9]
```

I tried something similar to this but didn't get the expected result.

```
    std::vector<int> indices = {0, 1, 2};
    array(indices, indices);
```

Comment: This should work: `array(indices, indices).matrix().diagonal()` (I assume this causes no overhead compared to a manual loop, but I did not check).

Comment: That will work if indices are {0, 1, 2}, not in case of {2, 1, 0}. I'd like to know if there's a general solution for this kind of situation. Also matrix() will copy the data. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: What output do you expect for `{2,1,0}` and what do you get? In general, `.matrix()` does not copy -- but I did not check how well it works in combination with slices.

Comment: If rowIndices are {0, 1, 2} and colIndices are {2, 1, 0} the output should be {3, 5, 7}.

Comment: `3 5 7` is exactly what I get: https://godbolt.org/z/o9esej9c1